# Removing values from one list from another list but preserving duplicates?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have two lists of objects in C#. One big, one small. For the sake of illustration let's say they look kinda like this...

```
List A                List B

Cat                   Mouse
Dog                   Cat
Mouse                 Dog
Cow
Dog
Cat
Dog
```

I want to remove the values in List B from List A, but only once for each occurrence.

So since 'Cat' and 'Dog' are in List A more than once, after the removal, there would still be one entry for 'Cat' and two entries for 'Dog' still in List A.

Does that make sense? Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: What are the animals, strings? Classes?

Comment: `foreach(var elem in listB) listA.Remove(elem);`? Does the thing in your list implement things like `IEquatable<T>` etc.?

Comment: They're List<object> but the list is always going to be full of ints. There's a reason it has to be List<object> and not List<int> though.

Comment: if the list will always be filled with int's then why would you need to make it List<object> please show us an example of what you will be truly working with.. you make zero sense in your comment

Comment: It's hard to make sense of an entire library of code in one comment. You can just trust that List<object> has to be that way. The question has been answered anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(var listBItem in listB)
{
    var index = listA.IndexOf(listBItem);
    if (index > -1) listA.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

or the shorter

```
listB.ForEach(i => listA.Remove(i));
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm dumb. Don't know why I didn't think of something that simple and obvious.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var item in ListB)
{
    ListA.Remove(item);
}
```